# I have a Canon 7D, a Yongnuo YN685, with its trigger and an AmazonBasics flash. I need to fire both remotely

Tags: canon, yongnuo

So, I need to fire both the Canon and the Amazon Flash at the same time. I know Amazon has a built in optical receiver, however this will not help because the flash will be inside a softbox, thus blocking the optical communication. I have the trigger for the YN685 (with its built in receiver) which I would put on top of the camera.

Both the Yongnuo and the Amazon flash have PC slots, so I don't know if I can connect a PC cable from one flash to the other and fire the Yngnuo with the trigger.

Alternatively, I was wondering if I could use the trigger on top of the camera for the Yongnuo Flash and use a PC cable from the Amazon flash to the camera's PC slot (Which is located on one of the sides of the camera).

Thank you!

Comment: Did you _try_ using the optical slave? Sometimes flashes _can_ be optically triggered through softboxes (even with "smart" optical slaving); depends on your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just buy a YN622 radio transceiver, set it to receive, and attach it to the Amazon Basic flash's hot foot?

(Since the YN685 has an internal YN622 receiver, I'm assuming you are using a YN622C or YN622C-TX to trigger it. The YN685 also can be set to receive manual only signals from a YN560-TX/RF603/RF605 transmitter. *If you are triggering the YN685 with a YN560-TX or RF/603/RF605 transmitter*, you could use either a YN622C made after December 2014 set to YN560 receive mode or use an RF603 or RF605 to trigger the Amazon Basics flash.)

The Amazon Basic flash's power will still need to be controlled manually via the flash's own control panel, but the YN622 will trigger the flash to fire in sync with the camera. YN622 transceivers also have a PC port that would allow you to trigger it via a PC cable between the YN622 and the Amazon Basics flash.

> Both the Yongnuo and the Amazon flash have PC slots, so I don't know if I can connect a PC cable from one flash to the other and fire the Yngnuo with the trigger.

The PC port on the YN685 is a "receive" only port. It does not "send" a signal when the YN685 is triggered via wireless or the hot foot. After playing around with a YN568EX II, YN685, and YN622C triggers I can conform that to be the case. When I trigger the YN685 via a YN622C-TX it does not trigger a YN568EX II connected to the YN685 via a PC cord. When the same cord is connected directly to the YN622C-TX (or a YN622C), it does fire the YN568EX II.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of the YN622, but the receiver is more expensive than the flash itself. The Amazon Flash has its own PC connection, so does the YN685. Can I put a cable between both and trigger YN with the transmitter? Also RF603/605 can't be triggered by the YN622C-TX trigger, so I would lose TTL capability for the YN flash.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the PC port on the YN685 is for triggering the YN685 based on receiving a signal from the PC port of a camera or trigger, and not for sending a "fire" signal to another device. Unfortunately, at the moment I don't have anything else handy to try and fire via a PC cable from my YN685.

Comment: @ManuAlv It would have been helpful if you had specified in the question you were using a YN622C-TX on the camera. Absent that, I had to cover both possible bases: That you were using either a YN622C (transceiver or TX) or a YN560/RF605/RF603 transmitter. The YN685 can receive signals from either protocol.

Comment: I've confirmed the PC port on the YN685 is "receive only." When I trigger the YN685 via a YN622C-TX it does not trigger a YN568EX II connected to the YN685 via a PC cord. When the same cord is connected directly to the YN622C-TX (or a YN622C), it does fire the YN568EX II.

Comment: "I thought of the YN622, but the receiver is more expensive than the flash itself." Have you priced a very long PC cord that is heavy duty enough to stand up to repeated use of what you want to do?

Comment: I think I will try what you said, having the cable attached to the YN622C-TX so I can trigger the YN685 wireless and the Amazon flash by cable.

Answer (score 0):

A really cheap option is to buy an optical slave trigger. It is a small sensor that can be on the external side of the softbox, to receive the light from another flash and trigger the flash inside via a cable.

You only need to set it up in a way that it does not fire with the pre-flash of your TTL flash.

Another option is to buy a radio receiver and a trigger. See Michael Clark's answer.

Comment: Can't I just throw a cable from the YN to the Amazon flash?

Comment: A PC cable that's very long and heavy duty enough to strand up to repeated use will cost more than a YN622 receiver...